# Error "Maximum Characters Exceeded in SQL Statement EDIT: Issue Displaying Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Thank you for helping. I am brand new to SQL programming (as in, this is my first assignment) and I completely don't understand why this is not working.
My goal is just to make this into a simple table. I was asked to use the SWL interpreter from sqlcourse.com, and when I put in the program I get the error "Maximum characters exceeded in SQL statement." Each time I check my statement I'm missing where the error is. Help please?

My Statement:

```
create table Marchetta1
(CustomerNum number(15), CustomerName char(15), 
 Street varchar(15), City char(15), 
 State char(2), Zip number(5), Balance number (8,2), 
 CreditLimit number (8,2), RepNum varchar (5));

insert into Marchetta1
(CustomerNum, CustomerName, Street, City, 
State, Zip, Balance, CreditLimit, RepNum) 
values ('123', 'Bob Smith', '8215 Cherry St', 'Grove', 'FL', '33331', '500.23', '1000', 'FP123');

insert into Marchetta1 (CustomerNum, CustomerName, Street, 
City, State, Zip, Balance, CreditLimit, RepNum) 
values ('456', 'Lucy James', '4711 Ohio St', 'Chicago', 'IL', '60644', 
'7000.44', '5000.80', 'FP123');

insert into Marchetta1 (CustomerNum, CustomerName, Street, 
City, State, Zip, Balance, CreditLimit, RepNum) 
values ('789', 'John Jones', '925 Main St', 'Grove', 'FL', '33385', '87.50', '2000.72', 'FP123');
```

EDIT: The fixes seemed to work and the commands are executed...but I have no way to check since my table is not displaying. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> "Maximum characters exceeded in SQL statement."

That's the problem.  Your SQL statement is too long.

What you have there are four different SQL statements.  You should be entering them one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, while inserting 'number' values into the table, they're usually entered without inverted commas. For e.g. values (123, 'Bob Smith'....)