# Maximum Characters exceeded in SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, character

So I'm trying to run this example code for filling in the rows of a table and then selecting data from the table, based on certain criteria. However, when I run the code I get an error saying, 'Maximum Characters exceeded in SQL statement'. I believe filling in the data into rows is working fine, however while selecting data, there seems to be some error. 
Any idea what's going wrong here? Here's the SQL code:

```
    insert into Emp902_Info
    (Firstname, Lastname, Title, Age, Salary) 
    values ('Jonie', 'Weber', 'Secretary', 28, 19500.0), ('Potsy', 'Weber', 
    'Programmer', 32, 45300.0), ('Dirk', 'Smith', 'Programmer II', 45, 
    75020.0),('Smirk', 'David', 'Designer I', 40, 75000.0), ('Dunkirk',
    'Plane','Designer II', 84, 99080.0), ('Polly', 'Sweet', 'HR', 35, 
    72020.0);
    select * from Emp9011_Info;
    select * from Emp9011_Info 
    where Salary > 30000;
    select Firstname, Lastname from Emp902_Info
    where Age < 30;
    select Firstname, Lastname, Salary from Emp902_Info
    where Title LIKE '%Programmer%';
    select * from Emp902_Info
    where Lastname LIKE '%ebe%';
    select Firstname from Emp902_Info
    where Firstname ='Potsy';
    select * from Emp902_Info
    where Age > 80;
    select * from Emp902_Info
    where Lastname LIKE '%ith';
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And which SQL tool?

Comment: Are you following correct format to insert into table? like `insert into Emp902_Info (Firstname, Lastname, Title, Age, Salary) values ('Jonie', 'Weber', 'Secretary', 28, 19500.0)` and `insert into Emp902_Info    (Firstname, Lastname, Title, Age, Salary) values ('Potsy', 'Weber', ' 
   Programmer', 32, 45300.0)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'm trying to complete an online tutorial. Here's the link to it: http://www.sqlcourse.com/insert.html Every time I try to run it, I encounter the same error.

Comment: Have you tried writing separate Insert scripts?

Comment: The code you posted is 100 % correct. You must have more code in your editor which seems to be executed. Or see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089855/error-maximum-characters-exceeded-in-sql-statement-edit-issue-displaying-table